# JGraphT: getting ranked solutions from e.g. KuhnMunkresMinimalWeightBipartitePerfectMatching

Tags: optimization, graph, jgrapht

I've defined a bipartite graph with two equal partitions. Let's say the vertices are:

(T0, T1, T2, Z0, Z1, Z2),

the partitions are (T0, T1, T2) and (Z0, Z1, Z2). All vertices of partition "T" are connected to all vertices of partition "Z" through weighted edges.

I'm using the KuhnMunkresMinimalWeightBipartitePerfectMatching class to find the optimum assignment. It correctly gives me the best assignment possible.

My question is: can I ask for several solutions, ranked in order of cost?

I've explored two options so far that did not work:

- first, I set the weight of the all the edges involved in the first assignment to a high value, effectively making that solution more expensive then other solutions. However, this excludes other feasible solutions.
- second, I removed the edge from the graph after it had been used in the first solution. But then the graph is not necessarily bipartite any more. Besides that, it again removes edges that could be a part of a different solution.

Is there perhaps a different class I should be using? Or some way to extract several solutions from the one I use? I'm just starting out with JGraphT, any help is appreciated.

Comment: With an integer programming model you can forbid a solution and find the next best one. Some MIP solvers have a "solution pool" to do this very efficiently.

Comment: There is some scientific work on that like for example [this one](http://www.research.relund.dk/publications/pdf/pedersen08a.pdf) (or a small chapter 5.4.1 in *Burkard, Rainer E., Mauro Dell'Amico, and Silvano Martello. Assignment problems, revised reprint. Vol. 125. Siam, 2009.*). I doubt many general libraries (or any popular) will do something tailored to this task. Erwin's idea might be the most easy one to get you going (although, without much experience, i'm always less than fascinated by the documentation about those solution pools in terms of what exactly is guaranteed).

Comment: Actually cuts are faster than the solution pool in my quick (random) experiment [[link](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2018/04)]. Cuts take less than 2 seconds for a problem with 2 x 100 nodes and 10,000 arcs.